# Dynamically add rows with jQuery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui

i have a table with single row (textfield) and **Add Row** button, when user click on Add row, it dynamicaly create another row containing text field. Also i apply autocomplete on that text field.Now that autocomplete function work on first row correctly but when i add new rows it dosn't work. Below is my code plz tell me where i m wrong

**Add row function**

```
function addRow(tableID) {
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
            var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
            for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
                var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
                newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
                //alert(newcell.childNodes);
                switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                    case "text":
                            newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                            break;
                    case "checkbox":
                            newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                            break;
                    case "select-one":
                            newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                            break;
                }

            }

        }
```

**jQuery Auto-complete function**

```
$(function() {
        var availableTags = [
            "Apple",
            "Dell",
            "Microsoft",
            "Sony",

        ];
        $( "#product" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
```

**Add row button and table with text field**

```
<input type="image" src="../images/add.png" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" />
<TABLE id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
 <TR>
   <TD> <INPUT type="text" name="product" id="product" /> </TD>
 </TR>
</TABLE>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, what happened here was that the new element you created dynamically had not been picked up by the jQuery auto-complete function because it is created after you call that function. So what you need to do is calling the jQuery Auto-complete function each time after you add the row(at the end of function addRow()).

Comment: yes i have the same idea but when i try its also not working, i dont know what wrong with this

Comment: Had a quick look and found that you were using id selector in jQuery while applying the Auto-complete, and you should be aware that id selector can only select the first element among all the elements with same id. You can simply change from "$( "#product" ).autocomplete({" to "$('input[name="product"]').autocomplete({" to make it work.

Comment: waaaaaw its working, thank u so much **Shuo Ran** you solve my very important issue.... God bless you

Comment: @ShuoRan I tried this  exactly but it doesn't seem to work . Is it a specific issue with jQuery version, i was trying with 3.6.1.